# Hugo: how can I add a class for the last post?

Tags: css, hugo

I'm using this `baseof.html` to add the class of `first-post` to the body tag so that I can use specific CSS on the first post of a series of posts which are paginated:

```
<body class="
{{ with where site.RegularPages "Type" "posts" }}
{{ $first_post = index . 0 }}
{{ if eq $first_post $ }}
first-post
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
">
```

But how can I add a class for the last post? With this, I get the error “can’t iterate over *hugolib.pageState”:

```
<body class="
{{ with where site.RegularPages "Type" "posts" }}
{{ $last_post := last 1 $ }}
{{ if eq $last_post $ }}
last-post
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
">
```

Docs for `last`: https://gohugo.io/functions/last/

Comment: I've re-read your question and I've updated the answer just now. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

*LE: I've re-read you're question and realised I had misunderstood your aim, initially. I've redone the answer, hopefully I got it right this time around.*

For adding a `CSS` class to an item while iterating them, i.e. displaying multiple on the same page, I kept the old answer below.

For adding a class on an item's own page, depending on its position in the global list, try this.

### The list & the sorting

Round up the items in `$allPosts`. By default, I think they are sorted by `.Date`, descending, i.e. newest first. To force your own order or criteria, you can use [`sort`](https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/).

```
{{ $allPosts := where site.RegularPages "Type" "posts" }}
{{ $allPostsByDate := sort $allPosts ".Date" "asc" }}
```

### The pages of interest

Get whichever items are special. For the first and the last, you can use their respective built-in functions; both `first` and `last` return arrays with one element (the page, in this case), so to extract the one element, you can use `index`.

```
{{ $firstPost := index (first 1 $allPostsByDate) 0 }}
{{ $lastPost := index (last 1 $allPostsByDate) 0 }}
```

### Compare with the current page

All the code in this example must be included in a template like `single.html`, which runs for each page. So, for each page that is rendered, you have one last check to make, to see whether the current page is one of the special ones.

I don't know Hugo that well to say if there's a better way of comparing two pages, but `.Permalink`s seem good enough.

```
{{ if eq $firstPost.Permalink $.Permalink }} first-post {{ end }}
{{ if eq $lastPost.Permalink $.Permalink }} last-post {{ end }}
```

### The whole thing

With the whole list displayed, for visualising what's what.

```
  {{ $allPosts := where site.RegularPages "Type" "posts" }}
  {{ $allPostsByDate := sort $allPosts ".Date" "asc" }}

  {{ $firstPost := index (first 1 $allPostsByDate) 0 }}
  {{ $lastPost := index (last 1 $allPostsByDate) 0 }}

  {{/* on the single page */}}
  {{ .Title }} &mdash;
  {{ if eq $firstPost.Permalink $.Permalink }} first-post {{ end }}
  {{ if eq $lastPost.Permalink $.Permalink }} last-post {{ end }}

  <br><br>

  {{/* on a list */}}
  {{ range $allPostsByDate }}
    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
    {{ if eq $firstPost.Permalink .Permalink }} first-post {{ end }}
    {{ if eq $lastPost.Permalink .Permalink }} last-post {{ end }}
    <br>
  {{ end }}
```

---

## Old answer

### Using Hugo last

I think there might be a typo there? I can't test now, but I would say that you need to have a dot instead of a question mark. I don't know what the `$` variable is, if it's something in Hugo. In fact, that would explain the error. `last` expects the second argument to be an array, and you're giving it a `PageState`. So it should probably be something like this:

```
{{ $last_posts := last 1 . }}
{{/* This will give you an array of length 1, over which you then have to iterate. */}}
{{ $last_post := index $last_posts 0 }}
{{/* or */}}
{{ range $last_posts }}
{{/* last post here */}}
{{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

### Using Hugo len

Following the same pattern, you could get the last index via the array's length. [Hugo's `len` function](https://gohugo.io/functions/len/)

```
{{ $last_index := (len .) - 1 }}
{{ last_post := index . $last_index }}
```

### Using CSS

You can drop the custom treatment for the first and last posts altogether from the templates, and use CSS pseudoclasses, like

- [`:first-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)
- [`:last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

So your posts wrapper can have a `.posts` CSS class, and then, in your stylesheets, you can have something like

```
.posts:first-child {
  /* first post, make it pop */
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
}

.posts:last-child {
  /* last post, make room */
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

This way, however, you shift the computation over to the client. I don't really think it's that intensive a computation, especially with only a first/last, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Thanks, but neither Hugo example works. And I can't use first or last child because I'm dealing with paginated pages of posts.

Comment: Hm, sorry about that. I'll try to get your example running, to see what's up. Just to be clear, you have, e.g. 6 posts, paginated, and want to apply a class `first-post` only on ID=1, and then, `last-post` only on ID=6, regardless of where they are on your current page? I'll give it a go